# Spring : Postgres: Error accessing index information

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am working with Springboot , JPA, hibernate. I am trying to create indices using the annotations for the tables

when I try to make  my spring boot app up it give the below error

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error
> accessing index information: public.table_name
> at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
> at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.convertSQLException(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:102)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getIndexes(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:763)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.indexes(TableInformationImpl.java:122)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.getIndex(TableInformationImpl.java:138)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.findMatchingIndex(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:344)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyIndexes(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:328)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:84)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:320)
> at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
> at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237)
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)

I am not able to figure out why its not able to access and create the index while its able to create the table ?

Any help appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Is there a better error message in the db server's log file?

Comment: Did you try to create the index with the same JDBC credentials from a SQL client (eg DBeaver) ? Maybe the table was created before and now the credentials' user has no privileges anymore.

Comment: @jjanes Do you know a source where I can find which postgres java lib works fine with which postres version and spring-data-jpa ? what my understanding is spring-data-jpa depends upon postgresql java lib which in turn depends upon pgjdbc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, actually I was on PostgreSQL 14.5 earlier after **downgrading** the version to PostgreSQL 11.13, it worked ! I am using this postgres lib under my build.gradle

```
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.8'
```